# Proof $C = A \cdot B \cdot A^{\top}$ nonsingular if $A$ has full rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank, positive-definite

Given are the matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. $B$ is known to be symmetric positive definite.

I made the following observation: The matrix $C = A \cdot B \cdot A^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is singular for $\text{rank}\,{(A)} < m$. Example:

$$
C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 8 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 8 \end{pmatrix}^{\top} = \begin{pmatrix} 25 & 100 \\ 100 & 400 \end{pmatrix}
$$

with $\det C = 25 \cdot 400 - 100^2 = 0$.

Is there a proof for the claim: *If $A$ has maximal rank, then C is nonsingular*?

Any hints or help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $B$ is symmetric and positive definite, there exists $D$ with $B=DD^T$ with $D$ symmetric and positive definite. Then
$$
C=ADD^TA^T=AD(AD)^T.
$$
From $\operatorname{null}(X)=\operatorname{null}(XX^T)$, and the rank-nullity theorem, the rank of $C$ is equal to the rank of $AD$; as $D$ is invertible,  this is equal to the rank of $A$.

So $C$ will be non-singular precisely when $A$ has  rank $m$. For the rank of $A$ to be equal to $m$ and maximal, you need $m\leq n$.

Answer (score 1):

**A basic proof based on contradiction for the following question:** *If A has maximal rank, then C is nonsingular.*

Let us assume that $A$ has full rank. If $C=A\cdot B \cdot A^T$ (square matrix) is singular (contradiction assumption), then the solution of the homogeneous equation $CX=O$ is not unique. So, pick two distinct solutions of the homogeneous system, say $X_1$ and $X_2$ ($X_1\neq X_2$). Using now the property that the product of matrices is associative:
$$ CX=A(BA^TX)$$
and the fact that $B$ is positive-definite (that is, all the eigenvalues of $B$ are positive leads to $\det(B)>0$ and, hence to the existence of $B^{-1}$)
there holds that $Y_1=BA^TX_1$ and $Y_2=BA^TX_2$ are two distinct solutions of the homogeneous equation $AY=O$, which is a contradiction because $A$ has full rank (that means, the null solution $Y=O$ is the unique solution of $AY=O$). That proves, by contradiction, that $C$ is non-singular.